Accelq - How to write a loop to click on next button if a element is not in page
I have to click on an element which is located in 15th page by clicking on next page button from page 1 in a web table.
How can I write a loop on to find the element in each page , if not found in  current page click on next page button  until the element is found .
I tired by using repeat loop but it didn’t work
